# How in JSON Schema perform array validations?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a following JSON schema snippet.

```
  "attributes": {
                "type": "array",
                "minItems": 3,
                "items": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "a",
                        "b",
                        "c"
                    ]
                }
            }
```

I want to permit all the documents, which would have at least 3 elements in "attributes" array. Their values must be "a", "b" and "c", but also on top of that I do NOT want to reject documents that may extend that list.
For instance, I'd like the following snippet to be valid:

```
"attributes": ["x", "a", "b", "z", "c"]
```

Currently my validation fails as there are additional values in the array.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With draft-06 you can use the keyword `contains`:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "minItems": 3,
  "allOf": [
    { "contains": { "const": "a" } },
    { "contains": { "const": "b" } },
    { "contains": { "const": "c" } }
  ]
}
```

With draft-04 you need to use:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "minItems": 3,
  "allOf": [
    { "not": { "items": { "not": { "enum": ["a"] } } } },
    { "not": { "items": { "not": { "enum": ["b"] } } } },
    { "not": { "items": { "not": { "enum": ["c"] } } } }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am on draft-04.

Comment: It does work! Looks a bit hacky, but it solves my issue.
Thanks a lot for your help @esp

Comment: You can pronounce this hacky double negation as "not all items are different from 'a' ", which is the same as "at least one item is 'a' "

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to my problem:

```
"attributes": {
            "type": "array",
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "minItems": 3,
            "items": [
                {"type": "string", "enum": ["a"]},
                {"type": "string", "enum": ["b"]},
                {"type": "string", "enum": ["c"]}
            ]
        }
```

But what I do not like about this approach is that I have to specify required elements in the order they are in schema.
For instance: `"attributes": ["a", "b", "c", "z", "x"]` would work fine. But if I mess up the order of required attributes, validation fails.
`"attributes": ["b", "a", "c", "z", "x"]` -- invalid schema.
Having that fixed would be also nice.